# hadoop command and SLF4J error message cdh in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, slf4j

The SLF4J error has been bugging me for a while now. It appears every time
I type any hadoop shell command before showing the output of the command.

```
$ hadoop fs -ls
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further
details.
```

This is a pseudo distributed installation of cdh5 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 9):

Currently cloudera cdh5 does not officialy supports Ubuntu 14.04, although in the forums it says it will support it sometime before end of year.

However, I found a workaround.

Edit your `hadoop-env.sh` and add:

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:/usr/share/java/slf4j-simple.jar
```

Where the `/usr/share/java/slf4j-simple.jar` should point to an implementation of slf4j present in your system (I simply did a `find /usr/. -name slf4j*.jar -print` to find it)

See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for details

Now the logs works

Comment: That worked thanks! Just putting here a pointer to download the jar if not already there `curl -o /usr/share/java/slf4j-simple.jar https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-simple/1.7.29/slf4j-simple-1.7.29.jar` (or whatever version you want)